# Branch.IO - No data is being read when "access_token" is in the query string

Tags: android, cordova, deep-linking, branch.io

I have recently integrated our hybrid app with an Oauth server and Branch.IO for deep linking. The server returns a query string where `access_token` is a variable. However, it doesn't get through.

Here's the sample:

```
token_type=bearer&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&access_token_expires_in=839&tokens_issued_at=1520393802716&state=XXXXXXXXXX`
```

If I removed the `access_token` parameter or just changed one letter (or mispell it) like `acces_token`, it works.

E.g.

```
 token_type=bearer&acces_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&access_token_expires_in=839&tokens_issued_at=1520393802716&state=XXXXXXXXXX
```

Could it possibly be a reserved or filtered word? We don't have control on the 3rd party `API server`, any suggestions to work around this issue aside from creating another server which parses the returned URL?

Comment: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking/issues/433. Here is the update on the issue.